# alignment issue in webpage - responsive css

Tags: html, css

I have an alignment issue, rather height issue.

Please look at 
    http://www.hashgurus.com 
- in desktop version the header - precisely where the logo is positioned and the menu looks good. On smaller devices/mobiles the logo height becomes too large and becomes clumsy.

I tried changing some parameters to change the height of the div tag but its causing other alignment issues. Any pointers on how to fix this one?

Comment: if it looks big them reduce the size using media query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at your css you need to add this to the media query:

```
.header_3 .menu_wrap .logo {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[image]